# How to assert that a page contains one of two possible texts (so an either-or assertion)?

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to verify that a page contains one of two possible texts. I know how to assert that the body contains certain information but I don't know how to incorporate the either-or construction in the assertion. Can anyone help me?

Below you can see the general code I use to assert that the page contains a certain text.
If anyone can show me how to assert that the page contains either 'Text1' or 'Text2' that would be a huge help.

```
IWebElement body = driver.FindElement(By.TagName("body"));
Assert.IsTrue(body.Text.Contains("TEXT"));
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Your post is not exactly clear, since you're asking for an `either-or`, but also for an `and`. I'm guessing you mean "how can I check the page only contains one of two texts: when it contains Text1 it *should not* contain Text2".

Simply using a [binary OR Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/or-operator) won't get you there, since `true | true` equals to `true`.

In comes the [XOR Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/xor-operator).

> For `bool` operands, `^` computes the logical exclusive-or of its operands; that is, the result is `true` if and only if exactly one of its operands is `true`.

Try something like this:

```
Assert.IsTrue(body.Text.Contains("TEXT1") ^ body.Text.Contains("TEXT2"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could perform the checks you want and store each result in a variable, then perform the assertions on the variables.

```
var text1Exists = body.Text.Contains("TEXT1");
var text2Exists = body.Text.Contains("TEXT2");
Assert.IsTrue(text1Exists && text2Exists);
```